# Content is not compatible as a PDF, using Snappy wkhtmltopdf

Tags: php, wkhtmltopdf

I'm working on a project. I'm trying to generate a report with my charts and dynamic tables. I tried to used *wkhtmltopdf* but I wasn't able to deal with the complexity. However, I read most of the answered to other question on *wkhtmltopdf* so I decided to try snappy which was a sugeestion. below is my code.

```
  require_once 'C:/wamp/www/Mamca/lib/snappy/src/autoload.php';

  use Knp\Snappy\Pdf;

  $snappy = new Pdf('/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf');
  header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.pdf"');
  echo $snappy->getOutput('http://www.github.com');
```

but the pdf generated does not open, error from the pdf reader states "cannot open file"

Comment: Can you attach the broken PDF?

Comment: http://mamca.be/mamca/apps/compute/file%20(5).pdf

Comment: @Arno did you get it

Comment: Yep, I'll try and have a look as soon as I can

Comment: @Arno i found the solution already.

Comment: Great, I opened the PDF file you supplied in a text editor, and it was a debug message pointing to a problem like that. Congrats on finding the problem!

Answer (score 2):

There is no need for working with snappy to convert html to pdf. After spending one day on snappy, i used simple exec() function of php to convert html into pdf.

```
$exe_path = '..path to your exe file..\wkhtmltopdf.exe';
$file_html_path = '..path of your html file..\report.html';
$file_pdf_path  = '..path of your pdf file..\report.pdf';

$cmd = <<<EOT
"$exe_path" --orientation "Landscape" --page-size "A4" --viewport-size 
"1280x1024" "$file_html_path" "$file_pdf_path" 2>&1
EOT;

//echo $cmd;die;
exec($cmd,$output,$return); 


Please note here:
$cmd is a command 
$output will return response of exec execute successfully or return error code and message
$return will return a boolean value 0 or 1 zero means success or 1 means error
```

Answer (score 1):

```
require_once 'C:/wamp/www/Mamca/lib/snappy/src/autoload.php';

use Knp\Snappy\Pdf;

**$snappy = new Pdf('C://DEV/wkhtmltopdf/bin/wkhtmltopdf.exe');**
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.pdf"');
echo $snappy->getOutput('http://www.github.com');
```

I just changed the path of the wkhtmltopdf and it worked.

Comment: I have tried the below code, it seems to be not working, receiving error "Failed to load a PDF document" what's wrong with this (downloaded snappy lib and installed wkhtmltopdf in Windows 7) <?php
require_once 'D:/xampp/htdocs/demo/pdf/snappy-master/snappy-master/src/autoload.php';

use Knp\Snappy\Pdf;

//$snappy = new Pdf('C://DEV/wkhtmltopdf/bin/wkhtmltopdf.exe');
$snappy = new Pdf('C://Program Files/wkhtmltopdf/bin/wkhtmltopdf.exe');
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.pdf"');
echo $snappy->getOutput('http://www.github.com');
?>

Comment: did you copy the snappy installation file to that directory and that of the wkhtmltopdf? that all you need. pay attention to that because i got the same error for days untill i did it right. snappy works very well compared to all the html=css=pdf converters.